# How does Rails group arrays of hashes during form submission?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

According to the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#combining-them) and [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1) Railscasts episode, when there's a *one-to-many* association between two objects (e.g. `Project` and `Task`), we can submit multiple instances of `Task` together with the `Project` during form submission similar to this:

```
<% form_for :project, :url => projects_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    Name: <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <% for task in @project.tasks %>
    <% fields_for "project[task_attributes][]", task do |task_form| %>
      <p>
        Task Name: <%= task_form.text_field :name %>
    Task Duration: <%= task_form.text_field :duration %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= submit_tag "Create Project" %></p>
<% end %>
```

This will result multiple copies of an HTML block like this in the form, one for each task:

```
<p>
    Task Name: <input name="project[task_attributes][name]">
    Task Duration: <input name="project[task_attributes][duration]">
</p>
```

My question is, how does Rails understand which

```
    (project[task_attributes][name], project[task_attributes][duration])
```

belong together, and packing them into a hash element of the resulting array in `params`? Is it guaranteed that the browsers must send the form parameters in the same order in which they appear in the source?

Comment: Duh! Just found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300201/does-dom-order-determine-the-order-of-form-parameters-posted).

Apparently this is required by the standard.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, ordering is retained as-is, as @k-everest self-answered as a comment to original question.

Those asking for HTML, see the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#combining-them) on how the attribute's `name` is parsed.

Example of typically bad ordering:

```
cart[items][][id]=5
cart[items][][id]=6
cart[items][][name]=i1
cart[items][][name]=i2
```

And that gets parsed by Rails into this:

```
{ "cart"=> {"items"=> [
                        {"id"=>"5"},
                        {"id"=>"6", "name"=>"i1"},
                        {"name"=>"i2"}
                       ]}}
```

Example source: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/07/11/get-and-post-parameter-parsing-in-rails-2/

The feature was added in Rails' initial commit, with method name `build_deep_hash`. For more history, skip the flaming/semantics war and go for the last post from the end here: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/215584

Answer (score 3):

if you are working with straight data and want to send back an array without using any of these @objects

```
<%= form_for :team do |t| %>
  <%= t.fields_for 'people[]', [] do |p| %>
    First Name: <%= p.text_field :first_name %>
    Last Name: <%= p.text_field :last_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

your params data should return like this

```
"team" => {
  "people" => [
    {"first_name" => "Michael", "last_name" => "Jordan"},
    {"first_name" => "Steve", "last_name" => "Jobs"},
    {"first_name" => "Barack", "last_name" => "Obama"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: The HTML created would make this answer applicable to a lot other people searching for it too, if you felt like adding it  :)

Comment: yep, the HTML would help

Comment: Yes, please provide the HTML.